# How to display Current Month and Day in PHP calendar

Tags: php, calendar

```
function build_calendar($month, $year){

    #Creating an array containing names of all days in the week
    $daysOfWeek = array('Sunday', 'Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday');

    # What is the first day of the month in question?
    $firstDayOfMonth = mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year);

    # How many days does this month contain?
    $numberDays = date('t',$firstDayOfMonth);

    # Retrieve some information about the first day of the
    # month in question.
    $dateComponents = getdate($firstDayOfMonth);

    # What is the name of the month in question?
    $monthName = $dateComponents['month'];

    # What is the index value (0-6) of the first day of the
    # month in question.
    $dayOfWeek = $dateComponents['wday'];

    # Create the table tag opener and day headers
     
    $datetoday = date('Y-m-d');
    $calendar = "<table class='table table-bordered'>";
    $calendar .= "<center><h2>$monthName $year</h2>";
    $calendar.= "<a class='btn btn-xs btn-primary' href='?month=".date('m', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month-1, 1, $year))."&year=".date('Y', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month-1, 1, $year))."'>Previous Month</a> ";
    
    $calendar.= " <a class='btn btn-xs btn-primary' href='?month=".date('m')."&year=".date('Y')."'>Current Month</a> ";
    
    $calendar.= "<a href='?month=".date('m', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month+1, 1, $year))."&year=".date('Y', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month+1, 1, $year))."' class='btn btn-xs btn-primary'>Next Month</a></center><br>";
    
    $calendar .= "<tr>";

    # Create the calendar headers
    foreach($daysOfWeek as $day) {
        $calendar .= "<th  class='header'>$day</th>";
    } 
    
    # Create the rest of the calendar
    # Initiate the day counter, starting with the 1st.
    $currentDay = 1;
    $calendar .= "</tr><tr>";

     # The variable $dayOfWeek is used to
     # ensure that the calendar
     # display consists of exactly 7 columns.

    if($dayOfWeek > 0) { 
        for($k=0;$k<$dayOfWeek;$k++){
            $calendar .= "<td  class='empty'></td>"; 
        }
    }
    
     
    $month = str_pad($month, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    
    while ($currentDay <= $numberDays) {

         #Seventh column (Saturday) reached. Start a new row.

         if ($dayOfWeek == 7) {
             $dayOfWeek = 0;
             $calendar .= "</tr><tr>";
         }
          
         $currentDayRel = str_pad($currentDay, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
         $date = "$year-$month-$currentDayRel";
         $dayname = strtolower(date('l', strtotime($date)));
         $eventNum = 0;
         $today = $date==date('Y-m-d')? "today" : "";
         if($date<date('Y-m-d')){
             $calendar.="<td><h4>$currentDay</h4> <button class='btn btn-danger btn-xs'>N/A</button>";
         }else{
             $calendar.="<td class='$today'><h4>$currentDay</h4> <a href='book.php?date=".$date."' class='btn btn-success btn-xs'>Book</a>";
         }
         
         
         $calendar .="</td>";

         #Increment counters

         $currentDay++;
         $dayOfWeek++;
     }
     
     # Complete the row of the last week in month, if necessary
     if ($dayOfWeek != 7) { 
        $remainingDays = 7 - $dayOfWeek;
        for($l=0;$l<$remainingDays;$l++){
            $calendar .= "<td class='empty'></td>"; 
        }
     }
     
    $calendar .= "</tr>";
    $calendar .= "</table>";
    return $calendar;
}
```

I created this calendar function on 30/11/2021 but now the date is 01/12/2021 but the current date isn't changing. I have tried debugging but I can't seem to find what's wrong. I even tried restarting my XAMPP control panel but the current month isn't updating to December.

What I want to achieve is to make the calendar automatically display the current date and month which is why I added a class of `class='$today'` to the current day. Any help would be sincerely appreciated. Thank you.

[screenshot of the calender showing the current date and wrong current date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iqopx.png)

Answer (score 0):

Some feedback:

- Each time you call `date`, you are getting a new date-time value.  Although unlikely, it is possible that your day could change between calls to `date`, e.g. one millisecond before midnight, then the next call could be after midnight.  You should make one [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) object and use it throughout your function.  You can get all the info you need from the DateTime object.
- In your  `if($date<date('Y-m-d')){` and `else` condition line, you are not checking for `>`.  **I believe this is your issue.**
- The `if ($dayOfWeek != 7) {` logic doesn't seem correct.  You are looping through all days of the month in your `while` loop, and then through the extra days again in this `if` statement.

Comment: Actually, the calendar's date was updated to 1/12/2021 yesterday (**without changing any code**) which was the current date but now the current date is 02/12/2021 but it's not changing. I think I'm having issues with the time zone. A school project got me starting PHP.

Comment: Thank you @Alan I checked the `if ($dayOfWeek != 7) {` logic and changed it to:
`if ($dayOfWeek < 7)`

Comment: - This just helps in completing the table cells in case there are no extra days on the last row so this creates empty cells.

- Also, I know it's not an excuse but I'm very new to PHP so I'm kind of having a hard time getting some things to work. I tried creating a Date Object but I don't quite understand how it works.

Comment: Sorry, I had to split the comments, the formatting rules I tried weren't applying and it made the comment look so messy.